# Postfixでのバーチャルドメイン利用時のエイリアス設定について

Tags: postfix

お世話になります。
Postfixでバーチャルドメインの機能を利用して、複数のドメインでメールを受信できるようにしています。
この状態でエイリアスを設定して、特定のプログラムにパイプしようとしているのですが、うまくいかないようでエラーメールが返ってきてしまいます。
何かよい方法はないでしょうか。
アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
環境は、Ubuntu 18.04、Postfix 3.3.0です。
以下にPostfixの設定の抜粋を掲載します。

### Postfixの設定（抜粋）

```
allow_mail_to_commands = alias,forward,include
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com,sub.example.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:30000
virtual_gid_maps = static:30000
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydomain=example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
```

### 「/etc/aliases」の内容

※postmapでデータベースファイルは作成済みです。
また、ここでは例として適当なプログラムを指定していますが、本番環境でプログラムが存在することは確認済みです。

```
test: "|/var/lib/test/test test1"
```

### エラーメールの内容

```
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
    test1@sub.example.com

Technical details of permanent failure:

550 5.1.1 <test1@sub.example.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table


----------------------------Delivery report----------------------------
Reporting-MTA: dns; xxxxx.xxxxx.com
X-ZoneMTA-Queue-ID: 17281563baa0008e63
X-ZoneMTA-Sender: rfc822; sample@example.net
Arrival-Date: Thu, 04 Jun 2020 21:56:51 +0000

Final-Recipient: rfc822; test1@ml.riku22.xyz
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; riku22.xyz
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 <test1@sub.example.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table

[以下、送信したメールの内容となるため、省略]
```

---

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mydestination は **local 配送**、virtual_aliase_maps, virtual_mailbox_maps などは **virtual 配送** となります。
aliases は local 配送でしか使用できません。

---

(追記)
virtual_alias_maps で「test1@sub.example.com」→「test1@localhost.example.com」に転送するといいのではないでしょうか。
localhost.example.com は mydestination にあり、virtual_* にないドメインですので、local 配送となり、aliases を参照します。

ただし、もう一つのドメインの「test1@example.com」は aliases で扱うことはできません(ローカルパート「test1」が重複するので)。

Comment: 返事が遅くなり、申し訳ありません。教えていただいたように1度ローカルに転送したらうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。